# Event Listener change variable depending on clicks over time

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

I've never really done anything like this before.

I'm looking for some javascript code that will listen for clicks on two divs '#prev_hover_arrow' or '#next_hover_arrow' and if the number of clicks per second is greater than 1 then set $var = x else set $var = y.

Sorry if it's vague never had to use this sort of thing before and my js knowledge isn't great. All help is appreciated!

Comment: what are you trying to do???

Comment: If the user clicks on the div more than once per second set a variable to x else set it to y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're simply looking to detect a double-click event, jQuery has a built-in event handler for that (keeps things easy):

```
$('#target').on('dblclick', function() {
  console.log('Handler for .dblclick() called.');
});
```

See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) for more details.